# CSS select direct children, but not if inside another nested child

Tags: css, css-selectors

So, if this is the HTML of an element:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ignore-me">
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <!-- I don't know how many <p> gonna be here  -->
    </div>
    <p class="child">paint me green</p>
    <p class="child">paint me blue</p>
</div>
```

**How can I :**

1. Select the children `.child` but not the ones inside the
   `div.ignore-me`?
2. Select them separately, based on their index order.

I tried to use a mix of `>` and `:nth-child(n)` like this:

```
.parent > .child:nth-child(1)
```

But, it doesn't work!

Can this be done only CSS?

```css
.parent > .child:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}

.parent > .child:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ignore-me">
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <!-- I don't know how many <p> gonna be here  -->
    </div>
    <p class="child">paint me green</p>
    <p class="child">paint me blue</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `div.parent > p.p`

`>` is the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator). It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the direct children of elements matched by the first.

```css
div.parent > p.p {
color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ignore-me">
        <p class="p">don't select me</p>
        <p class="p">don't select me</p>
        <p class="p">don't select me</p>
        <!-- I don't know how many <p> gonna be here  -->
    </div>
    <p class="p">select me</p>
    <p class="p">select me too</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @j08691, thanks a lot for your answer. I'm sorry, I was aware of this by was after a little more complex selector, my mistake! Now updated the question, can you please check it out again? thank you!

Comment: @user7607751 You could use `div.parent > p:last-of-type` to pick the last paragraph to style differently than the other.

Comment: Thank you, yes, this works, also `.parent > .child:nth-of-type(n)` would be even better flexible as well... If you don't mind updating your answer accordingly to accept it as the accepted answer? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer can be further simplified to `div.parent > p`, because `>` already only selects direct children.

```css
div.parent > p {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ignore-me">
        <p>don't select me</p>
        <p>don't select me</p>
        <p>don't select me</p>
        <!-- I don't know how many <p> gonna be here  -->
    </div>
    <p>select me</p>
    <p>select me too</p>
</div>
```

Regarding

> Select them separately, based on their index order.

you can use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), but be aware that `:nth-child` also counts `<div class="ignore-me">` as a child of `<div class="parent">`. So your first `<p class="child">` is the second child. You can then use `even` and `odd` to alternate between the children.

```css
div.parent > p {
  color:green;
}

div.parent > p:nth-child(odd) {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="ignore-me">
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <p class="child">ignore me</p>
        <!-- I don't know how many <p> gonna be here  -->
    </div>
    <p class="child">paint me green</p>
    <p class="child">paint me blue</p>
    <p class="child">paint me green</p>
    <p class="child">paint me blue</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Selecting direct nth p tag inside "parent" class

```
div.parent>p.child:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}

div.parent>p.child:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue;
}

div.parent>p.child:nth-child(4) {
    background: green;
}
```

we can slect odd and event children

```
div.parent>p.child:nth-child(odd) {
    background: green;
}

div.parent>p.child:nth-child(even) {
    background: red;
}
```