# Can someone explain how multiple inline nth-child() works?

Tags: html, css

For example I might have this:

```css
html>body>#wrapper>div>div>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>nav {
```

What exactly does that do? Can someone break down each div, ">", and nth-child()? Thank you. Trying to figure out how this works.

Comment: The `>` selector is to select a direct child of the previos element. means not a grandchild or anything else (decendent) only a direct child. `div:nth-child(1)` will select the first div and only the first, all other divs will be ignored.

Comment: Documentation about `:nth-child` pseudo-selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Duplicate for the `>` selector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758284/css-select-direct-children-but-not-if-inside-another-nested-child

Comment: I think this question is perfectly okay. Some moderators have voted to close it, claiming that it lacks focus. I disagree. You have simply asked how something works, which is a perfectly legitimate question. Unfortunately a lot of poor quality questions do get asked on Stack Overflow, but this question is not one of them. However, questions like this can often be answered with a Google search, so make sure you're using Google before you use Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BrettDonald closing the question was a correct thing. First he asked 2 questions: "what does the `>` sign mean"  and what "does `nth-child` mean". That is exactly missing focus (askign more then 1 questiosn". Despite of that, a quick google search would give him tons of documentations, guides, tutorials... Last but not least, there also tons of duplicates about it using SO. The question was to broad and un-focused. Aswell it was missing basic research efford. If he would have attempted to break-down the selectors himself and stated where he gets stuck it would have been different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` is the [child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). Note the difference between a descendant and a child. The css selector `.a .b` matches any element with a class of **b** which is a descendant of an element with a class of **a**, whereas the css selector `.a>.b` matches any element with a class of **b** which is a child of an element with a class of **a**. All children are also descendants, but only first-generation descendants are children.

So:

- `#wrapper` matches an element with the id of **wrapper**
- `#wrapper>div` matches div elements which are children (first-generation descendants) of #wrapper
- `#wrapper>div>div` matches div elements which are children of div elements which are children of #wrapper
- `#wrapper>div>div>div:nth-child(1)` matches div elements which are the **first child** of div elements which are children of div elements which are children of #wrapper
- `#wrapper>div>div>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)` matches div elements which are the **first child** of div elements which are the **first child** of div elements which are children of div elements which are children of #wrapper
- `#wrapper>div>div>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>nav` matches nav elements which are children of div elements which are the **first child** of div elements which are the **first child** of div elements which are children of div elements which are children of #wrapper

This is pretty crazy CSS. Much better to give the `nav` element an id or a class and then use much simpler selectors in CSS:

```
<nav id="nav1" class="top-nav">
<style>
  #nav1 { ... rules here ... }
  .top-nav { ... rules here ...}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. How do I access text that is not part of an element? I have a nav bar, and the first part has the element to access that, same with the second, however the third portion (text) literally says in Mozilla Inspector No Element. Is there another method to find out how to access that? Thank you.

Comment: That is a different question, Kirk. Post a new question. But try asking Google first.